# How to prevent PHP pushed HTML tables exceeding the length of the page

Tags: php, html, css, screen, html-table

I am still a novice and would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

I am trying to prevent an HTML table from exceeding the length of the page. I am currently parsing a csv with PHP and looping the array information into an HTML table.

The table is to be shown on a static 1080p screen so the table itself needs to resize by shrinking cells instead of going off the page horizontally or vertically. I dont mind how squashed the cells become as they are colour coded with CSS.

I have too many lines of code to post here so I will just post my CSS style code which I have attempted to use to contain my table.

```
  <style>

    html,body {
        background-color: #F4F4F4
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0;
    }

    table{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        resize: both;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    th {
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
    }

</style>
```

I have tried different variations of the above to no avail e.g. overflow settings, resize settings etc this is just my current test.

I do not care whether I have to use HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery or PHP for this. I would rather not have to completely start over however.

Comment: It will always exceed depending on the amount of data there is to show. Why not limit your table to a certain row count and make like a fullPage.js horizontal slider to show the remaining rows.

Comment: You can make your table scrollable or limit the output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, unfortunately I cannot limit the row count as I need to display all information contained within the CSV with no user input whatsoever.

Comment: I would suggest javascript methodologies to adjust things such as font-size, padding, etc. in the table until there is not more screen scroll available.

Comment: Hi @MikeBrant, thanks for your comment, 
Is there anyway I would be able to set those to resize automatically?

Comment: @Alphadark4 Yes. It is possible, but something you would need to build in all likelihood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include this for your  tags:

```
td.wordbreak {
    word-break: break-all;
    width: NNNpx;
}
```

This should sort the problem of cells spiting out your table horizontally.
Replace the NNN by a number in pixels, that could be a fraction of the total you need.

So let's say you had only 2 columns, it would be:

```
table {

  table-layout: fixed;   width: 100%;

}

td
{   
   word-break: break-all;   
   width: 540px; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, this helped with the width of my table.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
table {

  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;

}
```

For more check [**Fixed Table Layouts**.](http://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/)
Hope this will help.

Comment: This would only potentially help in the horizontal use case.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, unfortunately this is something I have already tried which didn't help.